12 V direct acting solenoid valve doesn't open when connected to water line
I have a 12 V DC solenoid valve that works fine when not connected to water line. But it fails to open when it is connected to water line. It's a direct acting solenoid valve so should work without water pressure and I have good pressure on the input line but it doesn't open. I'm powering the solenoid valve via a 12 V, 10 A SMPS. I think the water pressure is creating the issue but I don't understand why it doesn't work.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Test the solenoid valve with a lower water pressure to see if it operates correctly. If it does, then the issue is likely related to the high water pressure.


If the water is flowing in the direction shown by the blue arrows, then it will enter in the area shown by the blue circle, flow up around the plunger seal, and apply water pressure to the back of the seal to force it against the exit port. The higher the pressure, the better the seal. (If you were to reverse the pipes then it could be forced open by increased pressure.)
As @winny points out, the solenoid isn't strong enough.
There is a possibility that you could give it a 100 ms pulse of 24 V to pull it open and that 12 V might keep it open. There are various capacitor pulse circuits that are able to do this.

I see. I was planning to connect it to a reservoir that is 6 feet above it and use gravity . But it seems any amount of water pressure and it doesn't open. One thing the plunger seems to be at a level where water can't get behind it to apply pressure but I could be wrong. I would try to apply more voltage to see if that makes any difference. Thanks for your suggestion.

10 m of water head = 1 bar. The valve is rated at 0.05 bar so, 10 m $ \times $ 0.05 = 0.5 m head maximum. (Welcome to the metric world!)

The plunger has a smaller diameter than the blue circled area so there is no obstruction to water getting behind the plastic part and apply force.

The valve is rated 0.05 MPa = 0.5 bar. So the water head should be a lot more than 0.5 meter. Anyway I did some more testing, I setup a siphon from a reservoir to the valve and it seems the valve works if the distance between the top of the reservoir and the valve is around 1 m.  If I lower the valve and increase the distance the solenoid can't overcome the water pressure anymore. Does the water pressure remain same if I siphon it or let's say if I supply it via a pipe from the bottom of the reservoir? Do you have any insights?

"0.05 MPa = 0.5 bar". Oops! You are right. My mistake. 0.5 bar would be 5 m. Water pressure will be the difference in height between the valve and the surface of the reservoir water.

You can try and be clever using voltage impulse to try and lift the solenoid but you'll increase the complexity and decrease the reliability. Just buy a new valve. I think you'll understand the specifications better now. Go for a safety factor of 2!

0.05 MPa = 0.5 bar. Most water utility systems work around 4 bar. Your valve is simply too weak to overcome that pressure.
